# setInterval function in AngularJS controller is being called automatically

Tags: angularjs

I have just started learning angular js. I was going through some tutorials and got a little confused in the following code.

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.person = { name: "Ari Lerner" };
    var updateClock = function() {
    $scope.clock = new Date();
    };
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      $scope.$apply(updateClock);
      }, 1000);
    updateClock();
});
```

From the execution what I understood is that the setInterval function will call the updateClock function in the interval of 1 sec. But I didn't understand this flow. Since I am not calling this function setInterval anywhere, how is it getting called? All I am doing is using the expression {{ clock }} in my view. 
Thanks

Comment: why no use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) to avoid using apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) is an inbuilt JavaScript method. It executes the function passed to it as first argument for every milisecond pass as the second argument. This method returns an id which can be used by [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) to cancel the interval.

Once this method is called it will continue to execute the passed function indefinitely until you call `clearInterval` passing the id returned by `setInterval`

Regarding your code, you are calling `setInterval` by passing the function to execute and `1000` milisecond. Since you are using angularJs you can use `$interval` service of angular which does the same  but it also takes care of running the $digest cycle so that the bindings are updated.

You can change your code like this

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.person = { name: "Ari Lerner" };
    var updateClock = function() {
       $scope.clock = new Date();
    };
    $interval(updateClock, 1000);
    updateClock();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` function requires to be initialized once. Would be initialized in your case when timer variable is first set and then would evaluate the expression `$scope.$apply(updateClock);` on an interval of 1000 milliseconds.

See [example](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval) and [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: Thanks a lot for those examples. They are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In this controller, **setInterval** methods calls itself every 1sec automatically, whenever it is called, it hits to **updateClock** method, and in this method variable '**clock ($scope.clock)**' fetches system current date and time.

In short, by using setInterval function (which hits updateClock fuction on every sec), you get current system time.